# Conflict between Spring Dao and Dao patter in exception handling

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, dao

Request Flow - Jsf (Backing Bean)  -> Business Layer -> DAO Layer ( spring Dao )

some article suggest that DAO layer catch all sql exception and should throw checked exception. Business Layer catch that exception and throw custom exception as per business rules.

My doubt is as spring hibernateTemplate already convert all exception into unchecked exception why should i throw checked exception from DAO?

please suggest some good approach. thanks

Answer (score 4):

> My doubt is as spring hibernateTemplate already convert all exception
>   into unchecked exception why should i throw checked exception from
>   DAO?

A) hibernateTemplate converts infrastructure-specific checked exceptions to RuntimeExceptions. This is good, your service layer should not have to deal with technology-specific exceptions. The checked exceptions you might want to throw would be of your own hierarchy, with names and abstractions that make sense for communicating failures across layers within your platform.

b) HibernateTemplate (and JpaTemplate too, for that matter) are no longer the recommended way of doing things. As of Spring 3, plain Hibernate (or plain JPA) should be used, transaction management and exception translation should happen via AOP only.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, there are two types of exception:

- Recoverable/expected exceptions
- Unrecoverable/unexpected exceptions

Expected exceptions would be caused by violation of business rules (for example, if a user tries to create a record that already exists, or a user tries to withdraw more money than is in his account).

Unexpected exceptions are caused by unforseen situations (e.g. your database blows up, bugs in your code, or a remote server cannot be reached).

Expected exceptions should be handled gracefully (e.g. the user should be told nicely that he needs to do something differently (e.g. try a withdrawal with less money), or the application should perform some corrective action.

In the case of such circumstance, I think checked exceptions make a lot of sense, because it ensures that consumers of a particular service deal with the exception.

In the case on an exception that you cannot recover from (e.g. if the database has gone down, or a SQL query is formatted badly), then you can't do much more than log the exception and display a generic "Something went horribly wrong, please tell the system administrator" message to the user.  In that case, the exception should remain unchecked caught at the highest level and written to a log that can later be analysed to determine whether a bug needs to be fixed or more resiliency added to the database (backups, failovers, etc)

So for example, if you've got a DAO that uses the HibernateTemplate which throws a `DataIntegrityViolationException` when a primary key has been violated, it would make sense to catch this and convert it into a business exception.  However, it does not make sense to convert all instances of `DataAccessException` to a business exception, as you wouldn't be able to do anything for example with a `BadSqlGrammarException` or an exception telling you that a particular table does not exist.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore "some articles". -- Sometimes a Framework did not support the architecture you want. In this cases you have two choices

- Modify the Framwork or use an other one
- Modify your rules

If you do not have a good reason for your rules, than the second way is mostly the fasted one.

*Btw: I guess someone will find the same amout of "some articles" that argue the opposite. (dont use checked exceptions at all)*

My personal advice would be using checked ecceptions for business related rule stuff, and unchecked for all the technical problems that can not been handled (for example lost database connection).